# Django-registration: full name not being saved

Tags: django, django-registration

I'm having an issue making sure the full name of my users are being saved in the User record upon registration. I'm using Django 1.5 and django-registration 1.0, and while I've accomplished this before with earlier versions of both django and django-registration, I'm having trouble getting this taken care of with the class-based views and signals.

The user registration creates everything OK, so I'm fairly certain I'm getting the signal wrong.

Here is where my code is wired up, `backends.py`:

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

from app.forms import MyRegistrationForm

from registration import signals
from registration.backends.default.views import RegistrationView
from registration.signals import user_activated

class MyRegistrationView(RegistrationView):
    form_class = MyRegistrationForm

    def register(self, request, **cleaned_data):
        username, email, password, first_name, last_name = cleaned_data['username'], cleaned_data['email'], cleaned_data['password1'], cleaned_data['first_name'], cleaned_data['last_name']
        if Site._meta.installed:
            site = Site.objects.get_current()
        else:
            site = RequestSite(request)
        new_user = RegistrationProfile.objects.create_inactive_user(
            username, email, password, site)
        signals.user_registered.send(sender=self.__class__,
                                     user=new_user,
                                     request=request,
                                     first_name=first_name,
                                     last_name=last_name)
        return new_user

def create(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    """ Saves the user's full name to the user record. """
    user.first_name = first_name
    user.last_name = last_name
    user.save()

user_activated.connect(create)
```

And in case I did get the signal right and there's an issue with my form, here is `forms.py`:

```
attrs_dict = {'class': 'required'}
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class MyRegistrationForm(RegistrationFormTermsOfService):
    """
    Custom registration form performs unique email checking to prevent users with the same email address from registering more than once.
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyRegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # adding custom error messages
        self.fields['username'].error_messages = {'required': 'Please enter a username.'}
        self.fields['email'].error_messages = {'required': 'Please enter a valid email address.'}
        self.fields['first_name'].error_messages = {'required': 'Please enter a first name.'}
        self.fields['last_name'].error_messages = {'required': 'Please enter a last name.'}
        self.fields['password1'].error_messages = {'required': 'Please enter a password.'}
        self.fields['password2'].error_messages = {'required': 'Please confirm your password.'}

        logger.debug('Registration form loaded')

    def clean_email(self):
        if User.objects.filter(email__iexact=self.cleaned_data['email']):
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("This email address is already in use. Please supply a different email address."))
        return self.cleaned_data['email']

    first_name = forms.CharField(label="First Name", widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=attrs_dict))
    last_name = forms.CharField(label="Last Name", widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=attrs_dict))
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the matter is in your forms.py. It would better if you can replace the whole `__init__()` class with a class Meta by using directly the Model mane.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work -- does class Meta work on non-ModelForms?

Comment: Matthew - Did you ever get this to work looking to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

The actual user is being created by the function create_inactive_user in registration/models.py.

You may want to try adding the fields so the model function looks something like:

```
def create_inactive_user(self, username, email, password, first_name, last_name,
                         site, send_email=True):

    new_user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password, 
                                       first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)
    new_user.is_active = False
    new_user.save()

    registration_profile = self.create_profile(new_user)

    if send_email:
        registration_profile.send_activation_email(site)

    return new_user
```

No guarantees this will work though! Best of luck to you!